# Input type=number is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

First of all , this is the problem on nexus 5 with default input method.

The problem is , if I use v4 fragment tab host with the edit-text (input type = number), when I type the number , then it will switch to alphabetical keypad, and nothing is input in the edit-text.

I am sure this is the problem with v4 fragment tab host as I tried tabhost it works, I use only activity instead of any tab host, it works. When input type = "text" , and switch to num pad , it works. I can capture onKeyDown event , too .

**The only fail case is input type= number and the edit text is inside the v4 fragment tabhost**

the layout of the tab fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_ratio"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the layout of tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

java of the main activity

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    public static LinearLayout tabBar;
    private String[] tags = { "home", "form", "calculator", "phone", "partner", "about_us", "settings" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec(tags[0]).setIndicator(""),
                HomeFragment.class, null);


    }

}
```

Also, I only found it happen when using input method named "Simplified cangjie keyboard" with nexus 5 . So I wonder how to fix it . Really Thanks a lot.

Comment: while typing number or Alphabets or special chars inputtype=number is not working